# Numeric data frame columns order incorrectly as string

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some hospital data in a dataframe, read in from a csv. I tried to order the dataframe by a user-defined column `col` and then by the hospital's name like so:

```
col <- 'Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia'
hospitals.sorted <- hospitals[order(hospitals[,col], hospitals$Hospital.Name),]
```

But I think I'm missing something; it seems to sort `col` like strings:

```
> hospitals.sorted
... # so far so good # ...
2749                                                   10.0
2831                                                   10.0
2891                                                   10.0
2837                                                   10.1
2824                                                   10.1
2774                                                   10.1
... # not so good # ...
2856                                                   15.7
2834                                                   15.9
2797                                                   16.0
2835                                                    7.4
2850                                                    7.7
2789                                                    8.1
... # there are some non-numeric values at the very bottom # ...
2806                                                    9.9
2867                                                    9.9
2884                                                    9.9
2808                                          Not Available
2913                                          Not Available
2911                                          Not Available
```

Just to confirm the column is in fact numeric:

```
> sapply(hospitals, mode)
Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia 
"numeric" 
Hospital.Name 
"numeric"
```

I don't know why `Hospital.Name` is numeric when it's clearly not.

Other things I tried to no avail:

- using `as.numeric(hospitals[,col])` inside of `order`
- removing the "Not Available" values before sorting

I may be missing something fundamental. Halp!

Comment: Try `str(hospitals)`?  You likely have a problem with factors.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In data frames, the individual components must be atomic vectors. You are including both numeric and character data in the variable you mention, and as such R will have read that as a character vector. However, due to the default setting of argument `stringsAsFactors` that character vector will have been converted to a factor. And hence it will look like the numbers are stored as numerics. Those are just labels however and you are being deceived.

Likewise, the `mode()` call is deceiving you too. Consider

```
> mode(factor(c(1:10, "a")))
[1] "numeric"
```

Yet this is clearly not "numeric" data. Next consider

```
> mode(factor(letters))
[1] "numeric"
```

This belies the fact that internally R's factors are stored as numeric variables and that is what `mode()` is telling you. `mode()` is the wrong tool for this job.

To test if a variable is numeric, use `is.numeric()` instead:

```
> is.numeric(factor(c(1:10, "a")))
[1] FALSE
> is.numeric(factor(letters))
[1] FALSE
```

As to the solution. The "Not Available" needs to be set to `NA`. You can do this when reading the data in by adding `na.strings = "Not Available"` to the `read.table()` (or whatever wrapper you used) call. That should be enough to sort out the character > factor conversion.

Top tip is to always look at the output of `str()` applied to your object to check that R has read the data in as you wanted it to. So you should do:

```
str(hospitals)
```

and note the types of variables according to R.

Regarding the other things you tried:

1. `as.numeric(hospitals[,col])` will produce the numeric vector containing the level ID for each element of the factor. If the factor sorts in a particular order, so will it's levels representation. To convert a factor (it's labelled version) to a numeric you need an intermediate step: `as.numeric(as.character(hospitals[, col]))`. This will not solve the actual problem you have here though, because you have character data in the variable and R won't be able to convert it to numeric. It will convert the `"Not Available"` to `NA`, which might have worked had you tried `as.numeric(as.character(hospitals[, col]))`.
2. By removing the `"Not Available"`, I presume by dropping those rows/elements?, will still leave the remaining observations in a factor. Which for reasons mentioned above won't work as it will alpha sort on the labels/levels.